# Read url and output new javascript src

Tags: javascript, jquery

So essentially on page load I want to do the following:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (document.location.hostname == "somemachine.poc") {
            var fileref = document.createElement('script')
            fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
            fileref.setAttribute("src", "myscript.js")
        }
    });
</script>
```

In theory and practice is this correct? for some reason I put it on my page and it doesn't work as expected, and doesn't even show up in the source of the page.

So what I will end up doing is checking for several domains, dependent on which domain a different src for the .js will load.

### UPDATE

The answers below helped me fix the issue, I have a new issue which follows on naturally from this question which can be found here: [Losing entire page DOM running javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934678/losing-entire-page-dom-running-javascript)

Comment: The ready function doesn't run until the dom is completely ready.  It won't be in the page source because it is loaded after the fact.  If you use a tool like firebug to inspect your code you would see the changes if there are no errors.

Comment: is there anyway of running it earlier?

Comment: I think you can use $.getScript here. Even so, can't you get the server to send a script based on the domain?

Comment: try to append the this "fileref"  to  header tag .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the script to the document.

```
document.body.appendChild(fileref);
```

It still won't show up in the source though. The DOM, as modified by JS, is not the source. You would have to use a DOM viewer to see it (e.g. Chrome Developer Tools or Opera Dragonfly).

Answer (score 1):

you should also inject your script element in the document, e.g.

```
document.body.appendChild(fileref);
```

creating element only is not enough to make it run as far as it's not appended as part of the DOM

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do but you never actually add the `<script>` element to the `DOM` in the code you provided. You would need to do something like:

```
document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileRef);
```