# Losing entire page DOM running javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This question continues on from this question:

[Read url and output new javascript src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10932278/read-url-and-output-new-javascript-src)

My latest code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {


        var oScript = document.createElement('script');
        oScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        oScript.src = 'converter.js';

        // most browsers
        oScript.onload = function () {
            $('#converter #form').load(renderConverter());
        } 

        // IE
        oScript.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') {
                $('#converter #form').load(renderConverter());
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(oScript);

});
```

The issue is on `.load(renderConverter());`. What this does is, it removes the entire DOM and prints what renderConverter(); asks it to print.

The function `renderConverter();` uses the following to print the html:

`window.document.write(html);`

I changed to:

`document.write(html)` but it does the same thing.

How can I force it to only print within the div I have run the call back on?. The div being `#converter #form`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `document.write` after the page has finished loading.

You should use jQuery DOM manipulation instead.

Comment: doh its amazing how easily I forgot that! sigh hopefully I will remember thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

When a document has closed (after load), any call to `document.write()` implicitly calls `document.open()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.open)). This causes the current document to be completely wiped out in preparation for new document content.

To manipulate the content of an element, use DOM manipulation such as `innerHTML` or `appendChild` or use jQuery's equivalent methods (since your code shows you already have jQuery loaded up).